# Devise: making additional parameters required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

According to latest Devise docu, I added additional parameter `:name` to my `User` model and adjusted `RegistrationsController`. It works so far, the parameter is taken, and I am able now to register the user with a `name`, but how I make this parameter strong required? If I do not specify it in the registration request, it still register the user without setting the `name` (in db then: name = nil). So how to prevent this situation and make `name` required?

here is the controller:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # Disable CSRF protection
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  # Be sure to enable JSON.
  respond_to :html, :json

  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]

  protected

  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name])
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have to apply validations on the sign up form. You can use two different ways for this

- **Server Side Validation**

  For this you can use `validates` helper. You can add following line in your user model (user.rb). Refer [this link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence) for more information.

  ```
  validates :name, presence: true
  ```
- **Client Side Validation**

  You can use **[JQuery plugin](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-form-validation-plugins/)** like for achieving this functionality.

  Please refer [this](https://bestror.wordpress.com/2013/06/29/validation-form-in-ruby-on-rails-with-jquery-validate/) link for implementing JQuery validation using jquery.validate()

Comment: Thank you, that made "name" required, so I must pass it now in the request to the server. However if I don't pass a `name` I am still getting response-code "200", but I thing it should be 406 in case of missing parameters.. is it a way to get it?

Comment: I need to see this. Let you know.